# When inserting SQL how to enable UTF-8 encoding?

Tags: mysql, utf-8, mysql-error-1064

I am trying to import data from `MySQL 5.1.30` to `Mysql 5.5.8`.

However I get this error message:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 2209: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''à¤—' at line 163
```

I think because of the Persian language it requires UTF-8 encoding.  How do I import with UTF-8 enabled?

```
INSERT INTO `language_data` (`id`, `lang_variable`, `English`, `Spanish`, `Hindi`, `Chinese`, `Farsi`) VALUES
(1343, '#my_challenges_button_find_challenges', 'Find challenges', 'Buscar desafÃ­os', 'à¤šà¥<81>à¤¨à¥Œà¤¤à¤¿à¤¯à¥‹à¤‚ à¤•à¤¾ à¤ªà¤¤à¤¾ à¤²à¤—à¤¾à¤<8f>à¤‚', '', ''),
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [UTF-8 all the way through](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a wrong literal value. The literal quote symbol (') must be repeated in string values -

```
INSERT INTO table VALUES(..., 'some text ''à¤—')
```

You need to find and fix this error in your script.

Answer (score 1):

`INSERT INTO language_data (id, lang_variable, English, Spanish, Hindi, Chinese, Farsi) VALUES
(1343, '#my_challenges_button_find_challenges', 'Find challenges', 'Buscar desafÃ­os', 'à¤šà¥<81>à¤', 'à¤šà¥<81>à¤', 'à¤šà¥<81>à¤');`